# How to reuse a thread multiple times?

Tags: java, multithreading, encryption, thread-safety, decode

I have this Pseducode:

1. Get user input until he/she enters "0"
2. Call a method `encode(input)` with that input
3. `encode` method is called by this code:

Code:

```
encrypt eddd = new encrypt();
while (!answer.equals("0")) {
    System.out.println("Enter String ,or enter 0");
    e.text = input.next();
    System.out.println("Please wait...");
    e.t.start();
}
```

Where `t` is `t = new Thread(this, "Encode");`, the problem is that once a user gives the input, `e` can't accept more inputs. I want that a user may enter 20 inputs in 30 seconds, `encode` takes 30 seconds to return output, So i want that user can enter 30 inputs and they will process in parallel threads.

4. It gives output
5. This continues till `0` is entered
   Like:
   Input

   Apple
   Cat
   Dog

output (as `encodes` return , time by time)

```
OUTPUT1
OUTPUT2
OUTPUT3
```

Error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException`

EDIT: i use this `class encrypt implements Runnable`

Comment: Use a ThreadPool. Check out the `java.util.concurrent.Executors` class that provides factory methods to create a ThreadPool.

Comment: You said you only want to take input untill user enters **0** , then you said 20 Inputs in 30Second, please be clear on your requirements !!

Comment: @NeerajJain I don't know how much inputs user gives, I have a while loop that continously asks user to give input input and stops when `0` is entered. I just gave an example that user may enter 20 Strings, So my code should open 20 threads but ist giving error on 2nd thread (reusing same object)

Comment: So you need to create a new thread for each set of input !!

Comment: @NeerajJain Exactly, but Java Gives an error if i try to run new thread using same object's thread.

Answer (score 1):

Use the same thread won't work here, if you think so better not to use a different thread but execute the encrypt method in the current thread. That is because here the program may start the thread again before that threat finish its work, which is why you see such errors. Best approach is using a thread pool. Where if no thread is available to run (all the threads are used) you the program will wait for the next thread to be available. Simply you can use [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to create a thread pool. See the code below. If you need to use single thread then use **Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()**.

```
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
//      ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();


        while (!answer.equals("0")) {
            System.out.println("Enter String ,or enter 0");
            e.text = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please wait...");
            Encrypt e = new Encrypt();
            executorService.submit(e);
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to start an already started `Thread` which gives `IllegalThreadStateException`. Make a new instance of `Thread` for different threads. For example :

```
class ClassA extends Thread{

  public void run(){
  }

}

class ClassB{

  public static void main(String arg[]){
     List<Thread> threadList=new ArrayList<Thread>();
     for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        threadList.add(new ClassA());
     }
     for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        threadList.get(i).start();             
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: So, if user gives 200 input i have to write th1 to th200 ??

Comment: I am new, please tell me how do i implement it in my Loop, as the number of input given to my program in not known.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the same  thread each time

```
while (!answer.equals("0")) {
    System.out.println("Enter String ,or enter 0");
    e.text = input.next();
    System.out.println("Please wait...");
    e.t.start(); ------> Same thread instance
}
```

Instead try to create a new thread

```
while (!answer.equals("0")) {
    System.out.println("Enter String ,or enter 0");
    e.text = input.next();
    System.out.println("Please wait...");
    e.t=new MyCustomThread(); ----> You can instantiate your own thread
     e.t.start();------> Same thread instance
}
```

Comment: I did this http://notepad.cc/coctano71 , Now it doesn't even call `encrypt` method.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
String answer="";
                encrypt e=new encrypt();


                while (!answer.equals("0")){
                    System.out.println("Enter String to Encode , else enter 0");
                    System.out.println("Please wait...");
                    e.t=new Thread(new encrypt(input.next()));
                    e.t.start();
                }
```

Encrypt Constructor:

```
encrypt(String en) {
        t = new Thread(this, "Thread_Encode");
        this.text = en; // text to be encoded

    }
```